# Error When Attempting to Upload a Build to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am getting an error while trying to upload a build to iTunes Connect. This is the first time that I have seen this error, and I can't resolve it. I have tried following advice from other posts, but that has not proved successful. I have tried removing and re-adding my account in Xcode, having the client change my role to Application Manager, manually managing signing, and attempting to use Application Loader, which returns the same error.

I have two teams associated with my account; my personal team and my client's team. I am trying to upload my client's application, which I have done many times without issue. However, I just started getting the following error today:

[image: Screenshot of application upload error]

I don't understand why this error has started occurring today after successfully uploading builds within the past few weeks.

Did something change on Apple's end that is now causing me to receive this error after successful uploads over the recent weeks?

Comment: which xcode version you are using?

Comment: I got this too today and I put a build live yesterday with the same account so this seems new.

Comment: @AmodGokhale - This is happening on the latest version, v8.3.2.

Comment: looks like lot of users are facing similar issues.. https://twitter.com/hashtag/itunesconnect?f=tweets&vertical=default , wait it out.. Few reported success with Application Loader ( Issue looks like on server side )

Answer (score 6):

As [@AmodGokhale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2323607/amod-gokhale) pointed out, this is likely a glitch on Apple's side. I just tried to upload with the Application Loader and can confirm that it works.

If you are not familiar with the Application Loader, here is how you do it.

- Archive your project
- Export -> Save for iOS App Store Deployment (save it where you can easily find it).
- Xcode -> Services -> Open developer tool -> Application Loader
- Deliver your app

Comment: I have tried using Application Loader as well, but I can't get beyond the login. I get the same error message when I enter my credentials and attempt to authenticate.

Comment: @NickKohrn - Hmmm... That's odd. Are you able to log in to the Application Loader at all? I haven't used it for a while and had to create an app‑specific password for my Apple ID. The normal password for your account won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to. I get the first error message when attempting to authenticate with Application Loader. I have tried using an application-specific password as well without success. I have seen many posts that reference users having to create another user in iTunes Connect. I don't intend to go that route since Apple allows multiple teams per developer account. It seems like a hack of a solution.

Comment: Yes, that's not required. My account is associated with 5 teams and has been for several months so that's not the issue.

Comment: Application Loader helped in my case as well (as usual). Again and again there are all kind of problems with uploading to ITC from within Xcode, while Application Loader works most of the times, if I am facing problems with uploading to ITC. It seems ridiculous, that Apple doesn't seem to be able to get it right in Xcode, if Application Loader is one of Xcode own tools and works most of the times...

Comment: I'm having this problem as well and when I uploaded with the Application Loader I got an invalid binary error.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here - I had to use the application loader.
As said above you have to generate an application specific password.
This can be done here:
https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage
Look for "APP-SPECIFIC PASSWORDS" in the "Security" section, and click "Generate Password…"  I typed "Loader" for the "Password Label" and then cut and paste the password generation into the login screen of the Application Loader.

All seemed to be straight forward from then on.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. It's a frustration. However, when I use an application-specific password, it gives me the same error as Xcode gives me. Using an application-specific password doesn't fix the issue in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i do what apple recommend and i will be able to upload my app using Application Loader.

Apple respond:

Thank you for contacting App Store Developer Support. My name is Camai, and I'll be assisting you today with your upload error.

We are aware of this issue and are working to resolve it. It occurs intermittently and might be resolved by retrying your delivery from Xcode. As an alternative, you can export your IPA from Xcode and upload it using Application Loader or altool.

For more information on using Application Loader and altool, please see the Using Application Loader guide: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf.

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to reply to this email, or contact us by phone. We are happy to help.

Worldwide Telephone Support
https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome the issue by uploading with Application Loader.
But there is a catch here, the Application Loader v3.6 which came with XCode works and the 3.0 version which was suggested by iTunes Connect portal does not work.

Go to XCode menu XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader